# Sitecore 8: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel'

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm randomly getting the following error when I try to login to the Sitecore back end.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Mvc.Presentation.ExperienceAnalyticsLineChartViewModel'.
```

[image]

I experience this issue after I have build the Sitecore link databases using Sitecore Launchpad --> Control Panel --> Rebuild link databases.

When I clear the Sitecore cache using http://{your website}/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx this is error is not throwing for sometime.

Is there anyway to eliminate this error permanently ?

Comment: These look like default Sitecore files, have you changed any of them? It may be some corrupt files/DLLs, you could try deploying a clean version from the zip of the Sitecore web root.

Answer (score 12):

When you Remove Broken Links on the Core database, the `Model` property of the `ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart` rendering is erroneously deleted.

1. Navigate to the Core database in the Content Editor of your Sitecore instance at `http://{your-sitecore-url}/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?sc_content=core`.
2. Navigate to the `ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart` rendering in the item tree at `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Common/Layouts/Renderings/ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart`.
3. Set the `Model` field to `Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Mvc.Presentation.ExperienceAnalyticsLineChartViewModel, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client`.
4. Save the item and click OK if prompted that the item contains broken links.
5. Log back into Sitecore and the Launchpad will load.

Answer (score 2):

In your view you're using **Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Mvc.Presentation.ExperienceAnalyticsLineChartViewModel**  instead of **Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel** witch is the default.

If you want to use your own model you have to register it in Sitecore
Navigate to **/sitecore/layout/Models** and add a new model in the model type add "**Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Mvc.Presentation.ExperienceAnalyticsLineChartViewModel, YourAssemblyName**"
go to your View rendering item in sitecore and select your model in the Model field.

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/109 looks like they have same issue like you